# How to align html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using display `flex` to display multiple items in one big container (`parentDiv`). The code is working fine but I get big problems with horizontal centering the items *(especially If there are only a few items they should get horizontally centered)* so I was using `justify-content` what leads to big issues:

> The `parent div` is not able to display all `items` anymore. The first item that gets displayed is the item "04" while it should be "01". How to avoid this?

Please have a look at this code:

```css
#bigDiv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#parentDiv {
  width: 90%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  flex: 0 0 4%;
  margin: 0 3%;
}

.item::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigDiv">
  <div id="parentDiv">
    <div class="item">01</div>
    <div class="item">02</div>
    <div class="item">03</div>
    <div class="item">04</div>
    <div class="item">05</div>
    <div class="item">06</div>
    <div class="item">07</div>
    <div class="item">08</div>
    <div class="item">09</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>
    <div class="item">12</div>
    <div class="item">13</div>
    <div class="item">14</div>
    <div class="item">15</div>
    <div class="item">16</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See this image:

[image]

**My intentions**: The parent div should be able to show all of the items (starting with "01" - and the last element should be the "16"-one)

**Note**: If there are only 4 or less items they should get centered horizontally. *(The reason why I added justify-content)*.

Comment: Can you very clearly state your desired intention

Comment: How about adding `flex-wrap: wrap` to the `#parentDiv` ?

Comment: So please have a look at the image, I hope you get it :) @JGallardo

Comment: Why I should edit "flex-wrap: wrap" ? That will kill it all :ß @Belder

Comment: _My intentions: The parent div should be able to show all of the items_ then just reduce the left/right margin, to lets say 1%, problem solved. I personally don't see why you'd use the `justify-content: center;` here, not necessary, just fine without.

Comment: Nope this is not working because there could be at least 300x items. And I need a big spacing between them. In my case 3%. @VXp

Comment: "I personally don't see why you'd use the justify-content: center; here, not necessary, just fine without." Because there could be just 2 items. And they SHOULD get horizontal centered! Not aligned left.@VXp

Comment: You can't just show all 16 items, not with the defined margins & initial width.

Comment: A possible fix is to use ElAoutar's answer, with `display: inline-block` and `text-align:center`. Frankly, I'm surprised it works. If it did (center) correctly, you'd have the same problem (described in my answer). But it looks like the parent (at least in Chrome) stops centering its children in order to allow scrolling, only letting them grow towards the right side once they exceed `100%`. It's "*wrong"*, but it's exactly what you're after :)

Comment: @jonas00, no it's not our job to go and do your work. we are doing you a favor but you have to at least do your part by making your question very clear.

Answer (score 2):

You're fiting `160%` into `100%`. And you want it centered. And it works: the `160%` total width of the resulting children is nicely centered.

But you're also expecting whatever is outside the parent to be accessible.

It's pretty much like making a child element go outside of its parent by -30% to the left or to the top (by any other method) and expecting the parent to allow you to scroll to it. It's not going to happen!

If it did, the child would no longer be placed at `-30%`, it would be placed at `0%`. Scrollbars will never scroll to left or top negative space. It's by design. You need to take it into consideration when designing your page.

Whenever you center a bigger child into a smaller parent you won't be able to use parent's scrollbars to scroll to the beginning of the child. So ***anything*** preventing the child positioning in the parent's left negative space will fix it.